# SQL query for retrieving the count of matching value pairs from a single table with different foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a mind-bending problem with a MySQL / MariaDB query, with a table structure as follows:

**event**

- **id** INT(11)
- **time** DATETIME
- **description** VARCHAR(1000)

**report**

- **id** INT(11)
- **event_fk** INT(11)   Refers to event
- **reporttemplate_fk** INT(11)   Refers to reporttemplate

**reporttemplate**   Localized report templates. Types: before event / after event, for each language

- **id** INT(11)
- **type** VARCHAR(255)
- **name** VARCHAR(255)
- **template** VARCHAR(10000)

**reportvalue**

- **report_fk** INT(11)         Refers to report
- **key** VARCHAR(255)
- **value** VARCHAR(255)

There are two kinds of **reporttemplate**s, one for **before** event (all events have this) and one for **after** event (only some events have this). There are tens of different reportvalues for **before** report, and a subset of around a dozen reportvalues for **after** report.

The problem is this: how can i form a query that calculates, for each **event**, the count of matching key-value-pairs for before- and after-reports in **reportvalue**-table, when reports of both types exist for the event?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
select
    e.id
    count(before.id),
    count(after.id)
from
    event e
    join reporttemplate before on e.id = before.event_fk and before.type = 'BEFORE'
    join reporttemplate after on e.id = after.event_fk and after.type = 'AFTER'
group by
    e.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replies, i was going to try the JOIN-route, but managed to pull through with this:

```
select 
    v1.key, 
    count(*) 
from 
    reportvalue v1, 
    reportvalue v2, 
    report r1, 
    report r2, 
    event e 
where 
    e.status = "RESOLVED" // status-column was missing from original question
    and r1.event_fk = e.id 
    and r2.event_fk = e.id 
    and r1.reporttemplate_fk = [report_template_before_id] // parametrized
    and r2.reporttemplate_fk = [report_template_after_id] // parametrized
    and v1.report_fk = r1.id 
    and v2.report_fk = r2.id 
    and v1.key = v2.key 
    and v1.value <> v2.value 
group by 
    key;
```

This seems to give the correct number of non-matching key-value pairs per event, which is the result i really needed here.